# Issue when running Modelsim-Altera

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, intel, modelsim, quartus, intel-fpga

I'm running Quartus Prime Lite 16.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 and I want to start using Models-Altera, but when I click on "Tools"->"Run simulation tool"->"RTL simulation" it shows me a pop up window saying that I need to point to my license (please see the picture attached), but before running the Quartus setup installation I specifically selected the Models free version.
[image]

Comment: please share with us your code snippets, error logs, or any useful information.

Comment: also avoid uploading code as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Signal Tap Analyzer, also requesting pointing to a licence or some similar wording. Maybe the solution applies also for the RTL simulation.
The solution that worked for me was to go to the Tools->Options->internet connectivity and enable “talkback options”.

I had found the solution here: https://mil.ufl.edu/4712/docs/SignalTap_Tutorial.pdf